# Filter specific data from table

Tags: mysql

Hi there hope someone can help me out, how can i filter multiple values from columns in this case `pstatus` `0` and `1` only?

something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE pstatus = 0 and 1 ORDER BY pstatus DESC");
```

Comment: Use `In` Clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE pstatus IN(0, 1)");
```